# Error: Multiple databases for CI4 and its uses default database as object validation in inserting data

Tags: validation, codeigniter-4, validationerror

By the way, this is not really a question. I just want really to share how to validate using a specific database in multiple database connections. Since I got this error and it took almost 2 days and thank you to the members of the Codeigniter 4 community who help me how to solve it.

I would like to share it also here for future references if someone encounters this error. Shout out to [kenjis](https://github.com/kenjis) for the help!

At first, I thought it was just a bug in the codeigniter4 that if I have a multiple database connections the validation rules only use the `default` DB group. But unfortunately, No. I just don't specify what DB group  I should verify.

In case you encounter this error, just add this on your controller:

```
protected function validate($rules, array $messages = []): bool
{
    $this->validator = \Config\Services::validation();

    // If you replace the $rules array with the name of the group
    if (is_string($rules)) {
        $validation = config('Validation');

        // If the rule wasn't found in the \Config\Validation, we
        // should throw an exception so the developer can find it.
        if (! isset($validation->{$rules})) {
            throw ValidationException::forRuleNotFound($rules);
        }

        // If no error message is defined, use the error message in the Config\Validation file
        if (! $messages) {
            $errorName = $rules . '_errors';
            $messages  = $validation->{$errorName} ?? [];
        }

        $rules = $validation->{$rules};
    }

    return $this->validator->withRequest($this->request)->setRules($rules, $messages)->run(null, null, 'other-db-group-name');
}
```

reference: https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4/issues/5654

Comment: could you please post a clear Question and a clear Answer, following these guidelines: [**Can I answer my own question**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), which might make your post valuable for the Stack Overflow community. thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.